# Generate pkcs12 keystore having pem sertificate and .key private key?

Tags: java, cryptography, keystore, pkcs#12

I have public key in  file with "pem" extension  and private key  in file with "key" extension(i don't know its format).I must use  them  in java programm for generating digital signature.How can i create keystore with PKCS12 type?Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use keytool: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html This is preferred java tool to create / update / browse the content of the keystore. Another tool is bundled in OpenSSL package.